# Display the number of entries in a channel

Tags: entries, count

I would like to display the total number of entries for a channel and nothing else is required to be displayed.

Is there a more efficient way to do this than the following?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
  {if count == total_results}
    {count}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the built-in Stats module:

```
{exp:stats channel="products"}{total_entries}{/exp:stats}
```

Or the [Query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html):

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT total_entries FROM exp_channels WHERE channel_name = 'products'"} 
{total_entries} 
{/exp:query}
```

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/statistics/index.html#total-entries

Answer (score 7):

From performance view is better to use query for this:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(*) as total_results FROM exmx_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = '2' "} 
total results: {total_results} 
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: I don't believe the count is necessary because the table `exp_channels` already has this data on column `total_entries`.

Comment: agree. At the same time if mysql with MyISAM, the COUNT number is stored in db, so it doesn't count all rows each time you try to count all rows and it will be not diff in performance.