# Getting total results per status

Tags: status

I would like to get the total entries per status for each category group.

I have 3 statuses.

the best thing I can come up with is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="any" status="Open"}  {if count == total_results}{count}{/if}{/exp:channel:entries}
{exp:channel:entries channel="any" status="closed"}  {if count == total_results}{count}{/if}{/exp:channel:entries}
{exp:channel:entries channel="any" status="test"}  {if count == total_results}{count}{/if}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I think there has to be a smarter way.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Actually, just re-read your question and you state "each category group", but the example is showing each channel. In my answer I've assumed channel.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance and simplicity...

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT status as status_label, count(*) as total_results FROM exp_channel_titles GROUP BY status_label"}
    {total_results} results for {status_label}.
{/exp:query}
```

You can just output a specific status using a conditional:

```
{if status_label == "test"}
    {total_results}
{/if}
```

Or you can refine the search if you have many other statuses you don't want included:

```
SELECT status as status_label, count(*) as total_results FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE status IN ("open", "closed", "test") GROUP BY status_label
```

Note I've used "status_label" instead of leaving it as just "status" so that it can be used within a channel entries tag pair without conflict of it's "status" tag value.

Based on [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/display-the-number-of-entries-in-a-channel) answer, albeit exp:stats doesn't work as I have it turned off and doesn't allow you to refine to status.