# Display number of entries of a certain categories in a channel

Tags: categories, query-module, statistics

I would like to display the number of entries of a given category within the same channel, and nothing else.

I've found this older question [Display the number of entries in a channel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/display-the-number-of-entries-in-a-channel) but that does not solve my problem - I cannot add a category_id to the stats module, and I'm not much familiar with the Query module - but still haven't found anything useful in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="2" dynamic="no"}
{absolute_results}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the very helpful add-on "Category Construct".  Something like this... all you need to know is the ID(s) of the channel(s) you want to count the entries for), and the ID of the category concerned.

```
{exp:category_construct:categories channel_id="{your_first_channel_id|your_second_channel_id|...etc}" cat_id="{your_chosen_category_id}" entry_count="true"}
    {construct:level_total_results}
{/exp:category_construct:categories}
```

Alternatively, this will output a list of categories and counts for a channel.

```
<ul>
 {exp:category_construct:categories channel_id="{your_first_channel_id|your_second_channel_id|...etc}" entry_count="true"}
   <li>{construct:cat_name}: {construct:level_count} entries</li>
 {/exp:category_construct:categories}
</ul>
```

HTH